# how to update specific rows of a dataframe using a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so guys, i have the following dataframe:[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ3nF.png)

trough this line of code

```
df[df['cities'] == '']
```

i'm able to select the rows of the 'cities' column that are empty like this:[filtered dataframe with only empty 'cities' rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uscsk.png)

and i want to update all of this empty fields with a list of values, for example:

```
empty_cities_list = ['Des moines', 'Seattle', 'Des moines', ...]
```

in the order of the list, like this:

```
df.iloc[729]['cities'] = empty_cities_list[0]
df.iloc[740]['cities'] = empty_cities_list[1]
```

df[729] and df[740] are just examples of rows in the original df that have empty values for cities.
how can i do this? i've tried looping through df and empty_cities_list using zip but it didnt work.
Just making the question simpler, how can i update specific rows of a dataframe passing a list of values to be used?

Comment: no, i need to replace the rows of the data frame that contains empty values, with the values in ''empty_cities_list''

Answer (score 1):

You can try following if the length of `empty_cities_list` matches the `''` num in `cities` column

```py
df.loc[df['cities'] == '', 'cities'] = empty_cities_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace('', np.nan)
df['cities']= df['cities'].fillna(pd.Series(empty_cities_list, index=df[df['cities'].isnull()].index))
```

**Explanation:**

First, convert all your `''` to `NaN` then replace the `NaN` values with `empty_cities_list` by using `fillna()`. `df[df['cities'].isnull()].index` this gets the indices of all columns which needs to be replaced.